# /usr/bin/ts: line 3: =head1: command not found

Tags: linux

I am using minimal centos 7 1810 and install moreutils for ts command.
After running ts command, it shows the following error.

```
/usr/bin/ts: line 3: =head1: command not found
```

Comment: How did you run the `ts` command?

Answer (score 2):

`ts` is written in Perl, in which `=head1` starts a documentation section.

Normally, you would call `ts` like

```
ts
```

or

```
/usr/bin/ts
```

and its shebang line would tell what interpreter to use.

You probably invoked it with `sh ts` or `bash ts` or similar. Don't do that.

Comment: thanks for the reply. Please check the following code.
The same issue occurred using this code.
`#!/bin/bash`

`f_file_descriptor_3="/dev/fd/3"`  
`f_script_name=`basename $0``  
`f_script_name="${f_script_name%.*}"`  
`time_stamp=$(date +"%F"-"%s")`  
`f_log=/var/log/cyops/${f_script_name}-${time_stamp}.log`  


`exec 3>&1 1>>${f_log} 2>&1`  
`{`

   `echo "This is a sample"`


`} | ts '[%d-%b-%Y %H:%M:%S]' | tee $f_file_descriptor_3`

Comment: Are you sure the `ts` you're calling is the `/usr/bin/ts`? What happens when you call `ts` and `/usr/bin/ts` from the command line?

Comment: When `ts` or `/usr/bin/ts` calling from the command line it shows the same error.
`/usr/bin/ts: line 3: =head1: command not found`

Comment: @Swapnilz: Does your `ts` start with `#!/usr/bin/perl`?

Comment: I installed moreutils package and run ts command. Also, I re-installed the perl and checked it. There is no error occurred. The ts command run successfully This issue occurred if system installed from minimal OS. 
I dont want to reinstall perl.